# Does Flask have an equivalent to Rails initializers?

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a Flask web app and would like to run some background services when the app starts up.

For example, in the web app you have the ability to add service accounts, routers ip's, server ip's and such. I'd like to have some background services running network scans, wmi calls and some other tasks to constantly update the database with relevant information.

In Rails I've used initializers in `config/initializers` to start some daemons:

```
# Start all the daemons to update the DB
system('script/daemon restart vs_updater.rb')
system('script/daemon restart c_fw_updater.rb')
system('script/daemon restart sans_updater.rb')
system('script/daemon restart sf_updater.rb')
```

Is there such an equivalent for Flask? Or should I just build separate scripts and run them in a different manner?

Comment: To me this sounds more like an operations issue than something that falls in the scope of Flask. I'd recommend looking into [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) for daemonizing your application's processes.

Comment: @LukasGraf, thanks that looks like a good solution. I'll read more into that.

Comment: From just looking at `supervisor`'s docs it can look a bit daunting at first, but you often can skip like 80% of all that. Maybe start with an [example like this](http://ewong.me/creating-and-deploying-flask-app-using-uwsgi-nginx-virtualenv-and-supervisor/) to get a general idea of how things fit together, and then later revisit the supervisor docs as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can add commands to the `__init__.py` file in the root directory and use subprocess to run the script

```
from subprocess import call
call("script/daemon restart vs_updater.py")
```

fab
http://www.fabfile.org/

subprocess
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html